# After log out in a django page I get to a page where I can´t log in

Tags: django, django-views, django-login

When I log out from any page of my application, it redirect me to:

*"/accounts/login/?next=/"*

From this page, I can´t log in again. If I try to log i get redirected to:

*"/accounts/login/"*

From there I can log right, if I tried to log on in other link, as for example

*"/accounts/login/example"*

It also login good and redirect me to the right place.

Can someone shed some light about my issue?

Comment: checkout the settings about auth https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth

Comment: Thank you. Yes At the beginning I  just tried to to set the logout page in settings, but it didn´t worked. What I did is make a new method for log out. I don´t know if it is the best way, but actually worked.